# How to validate JWT without library

Tags: jwt, token

I have a login page, I get the user email and user password from the inputs.
I created a "fetch" in my JavaScript file, and sent the user email and user password to my backend.
Since there is indeed this email and password registered in my database, the backend returns my token inside a json.
This is my token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJsb2NhbGhvc3QiLCJuYW1lIjoiVmluaWNpdXMiLCJlbWFpbCI6InZpbmljaXVzQGhvdG1haWwuY29tIn0=.YvasYRuuoreFzD5vzYJA5D33eDAyqcCDRWLu3ObRxkw=
```

I have my way to save it, I saved in the localStorage.
Now the user wants to use all the pages of the website, so I need to validate.

To do so, in the pages that need login, I created a new Fetch and passed the token in the header, like that:

```
header: {
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem("token")
    }
```

Everything alright so far. However, I don't know what to do when the data gets to my backend. Can you please confirm if my guess is right?

-> My token hits the backend, so I do the "reverse", that is, I decode the token to get the user email and password
-> I check if the email and password matches those of my database
-> I also create a new "jwt signature" with the email and password to see if it matches with the token's signature. I have to do this way because signatures have hash and hash can't be undone.
-> After working, I return a json saying to my front-end that she/he is allowed and If I want to, I return some data of the user to use in my page too.

Is that right? If not, can you please explain to me in a simple way? I have some issues to learn, that's why I couldn't understand much when I read some texts about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read more about it here https://jwt.io/introduction.

Basically, the token is base64-encoded so you can easily decode to read the content. Therefore it shouldn't include the credentials but only the id to identify the user (and extra data if needed). Then you can validate it using your `secret key`, it's depending on the algorithm you chose when issuing the token as well - here is `HS256`.

The last part of the token after dot (.) is the signature you need to validate. If it is correct then you know the token is valid and the current user from what you see inside the token.

> For example if you want to use the HMAC SHA256 algorithm, the signature will be created in the following way:
> HMACSHA256(
> base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
> base64UrlEncode(payload),
> secret)

*Use the library that you use to issue the token to validate this, best to read its documentation.*

For example, this is the content I decoded from your token:

```
{
  "iss": "localhost",
  "name": "Vinicius",
  "email": "vinicius@hotmail.com"
}
```

So if you validated the signature you can believe that the user who is using this token is `vinicius@hotmail.com`

Comment: I understand now, thank you :D
About the credentials thing, there is no need for credentials in my token because my 'signature' is a hash of the user email (or id) together with my personal password in the backend, so the user can't change and put a friend's email because he/she would need my password to hash them, right?

Comment: @Vialmeida yes, the `secret key` to create a valid token with a signature to be exact